# Trying to get a InputField input as a Int in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, input-field

So basically, an user is gonna type in the hours in a inputfield and im gonna get the amount they write as an int in my code.

```
public InputField hours, minutes;
public int wantedHours, wantedMinutes;
```

Basically what i want is that people are gonna write a value in the inputfields. One of the inputfields is gonna be the "hours" you see in my code and the other one is gonna be "minutes". What i want is to get those inputfield inputs as "wantedHours" and "wantedMinutes" you see in my code.

Comment: [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse)

Answer (score 0):

First I'll set the input type validation to only get `Integers`, this way you avoid to check if the input is a letter or number.

Then you can get the string input value as: `string wantedHoursString = hours.text`
If you want to parse that to an int variable you can do it with multiple ways with `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`:

```
if(int.TryParse(hours.text, out int result))
{
    wantedHours = result;   
}
else
{
    Debug.Log($"Attempted conversion of {hours.text} failed");
}
```

Comment: If you suggest `TryParse` you should also include dealing with invalid input (`if(!int.TryParse(...)){ ...}`) .. @OP for user input you definitely want `TryParse` ;)

Answer (score 0):

In editor for  InputField set ContentType as Integer:
[image]

Use in Code:

```
public void SetScore(InputField input)
{
    int score = int.Parse(input.text);
    GameManager.SetScore(score);
}
```